# How to return the firebase db's snapshoot's value? - javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, function, firebase-realtime-database

I need the snapshoot as a global varriable. Here is my code:

```
dbRef.on('value', snap => {
 var data = snap.val();
});

console.log(data);
```

when I run the code I get an error (because the data variable is not global). How can I make it global varible?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this would just be to move the definition of `data` outside of the callback, like so:

```js
var data;

ref.on("value", snap => {
  data = snap.val();
});

console.log(data)
```

But you will quickly realize that this doesn't work -- the output is `undefined`.  Why?

Javascript is asynchronous, the callback that sets `data` is not called until after a network roundtrip.  Meanwhile, the logging statement outputs the current value of data -- undefined.  This behavior is clearer if you write the code like this:

```js
var data = "no data yet";

ref.on("value", snap => {
  console.log("got it");
  data = snap.val();
});

function report() {
  console.log(data);
  setTimeout(report, 100);
}
report();
```

This will output something like this (assume the key's data is `from the database`):

```
no data yet
no data yet
no data yet
got it
from the database
from the database
from the database
```

So, now the data is in a global variable, which is the answer to your question.

The trick is making use of this and being able to tell when the data is available.  Most of the time, you want to do the work with the variable in the callback itself (in this case, just move the `console.log` inside the callback) -- this is what most of the [examples in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#value) do.  The approach you choose will depend, of course, on the nature of your application.

Keep in mind, the `value` callback will be called every time there is an update to the key (unless you use the [once](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-reading-once) method).  So, your code will also need to deal with that.  This is another reason that it makes more sense to do the work in the callback itself, or have your external code able to deal with changes in the data.